# Convolution with a Gaussian blur kernel works, other kernels do not

Tags: java, image-processing, filtering

I'm writing a small image processing program. Using convolution, I've been able to make a Gaussian blur work! My problem is when I try to use a sharpening kernel - It doesn't work, though as I understand, the convolution stays the same, only the kernel changes. Am i missing something?
My code:

```
`    public void convolution(float[] kernel){
        int H = myImage.getHeight();
        int W = myImage.getWidth();
        for(int band=0; band < writer.getNumBands(); band++){
            for(int x = 1; x < W-1 ; x++){ // all the x's
                for(int y = 1; y<H-1; y++){ // for each x, go through all the y's
                    int pixel = 0;
                    int counter = 0;
                    for(int i=-1; i<=1; i++){
                        for(int j=-1; j<=1; j++){
                            pixel += kernel[counter]*myImage.getRaster().getSample(x+i, y+j, band);
                            counter++;
                        }
                    }
                    writer.setSample(x, y, band, (int) (pixel)); //raster object
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

The resulting image does have edges standing out but it has very weird colors. Thanks!

Comment: What is `writer`? What does `writer.setSample` do with the integer input value? Does it clamp it to positive values? or does it cast it to an unsigned type? Either of those would explain what you see. You need to preserve negative values.

Comment: @CrisLuengo `writer` is the raster object of the destination image. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setSample(int,%20int,%20int,%20double) according to the documentation, I am unsure what exactly happens to these values